# Imposing LIMIT on UNION

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are working with some legacy code that is using a sub-optimally normalized DB.  The problem that we are trying to solve is best described with an illustrative example.
`hi_priority` and `lo_priority` are two tables that have the same schema, as defined below:

```
CREATE TABLE hi_priority
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(16),
  col1 VARCHAR(16),
  col2 INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);



CREATE TABLE lo_priority
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(16),
  col1 VARCHAR(16),
  col2 INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

In each table there is a 1:1 mapping between the `name` and `col2`.

The idea is to potentially `SELECT name, col1, col2` from both tables but limit the total number of distinct names (let's say 7 for our illustrative example), subject to the following constraints:

- Preference is to be given to entries from `hi_priority` table over entries from `lo_priority` tables.
- For example, if there are 15 distinct names in `hi_priority` table,
  we will select all rows with 7 names from `hi_priority` table,
  ordered by `col2`.
- If there are 5 distinct names in `hi_priority`
  table, we select all rows with those 5 names and on top of that we
  select all rows with 2 distinct names from `lo_priority` table,
  ordered by `col2`
- If there are some entries in both the
  `hi_priority` table and the `lo_priority` table, we select entries
  only from the `hi_priority` table

---

Let us assume that the tables are populated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO hi_priority(name, col1, col2) VALUES('john', 'kl7y5tis4yh4', 1), ('john', 'tiid6iywq02k', 1), 
('john', 'detawgsxz615', 1), ('amy', 'i6u4hhc1trjk', 2), ('amy', 'wdpt0t5vtmbt', 2),
('amy', '87z5wgdfztwl', 2), ('amy', 'oj98jjdpb5yv', 2), ('steve', 'hllaazonflf0', 3),
('steve', '0h22y66kq3ow', 3), ('steve', 'o04ksti7di60', 3), ('steve', '3qlylbzqfr51', 3),
('steve', 'wmisshywtb12', 3), ('bob', 'ku8wpf7d6ta9', 3), ('bob', '6t7mn60g0g18', 3),
('bob', 'qv0s7ho3jku6', 3), ('bob', '5qgz7dznzwvn', 3), ('bob', 'mm76nhimm6fu', 3),
('bob', 'k7nlpksc55t2', 3), ('oliver', 'gvf9kjewpj7h', 4), ('oliver', '24w5s30w5te6', 4);


INSERT INTO lo_priority(name, col1, col2) VALUES('doug', 'j205tzrsfmax', 11), ('doug', '0w7rcazbh6es', 11),
('doug', '6xswf8frsjaw', 11), ('john', 'iw7d14vtysz2', 2), ('john', '6lg667dygaz1', 2),
('john', '83uk5dcobpu5', 2), ('john', 'tl8cpzatv0n9', 2), ('mike', '2dsarwozpmci', 3),
('mike', 'hinn6w03wdib', 3), ('mike', '4sxbgyacmjob', 3), ('mike', 'm4q13ln9gctj', 3),
('mike', 'pnip9c8cejo9', 3), ('steve', 'faff9p9v96x4', 4), ('steve', 'd5mxqpd3k8zi', 4),
('martha', 'bxggn5t6d2xn', 8), ('martha', 't05mi47i4n6l', 8), ('martha', 'p30wmw2o6nty', 8),
('martha', 'wip6efajt9yv', 8);
```

---

```
The expected output is:  
+--------+------------+------+
| name   | col1       | col2 |
+--------+------------+------+
| john   | kl7y5tis4y |    1 |
| john   | tiid6iywq0 |    1 |
| john   | detawgsxz6 |    1 |
| amy    | oj98jjdpb5 |    2 |
| amy    | 87z5wgdfzt |    2 |
| amy    | wdpt0t5vtm |    2 |
| amy    | i6u4hhc1tr |    2 |
| bob    | k7nlpksc55 |    3 |
| bob    | mm76nhimm6 |    3 |
| bob    | 5qgz7dznzw |    3 |
| bob    | qv0s7ho3jk |    3 |
| bob    | 6t7mn60g0g |    3 |
| bob    | ku8wpf7d6t |    3 |
| steve  | wmisshywtb |    3 |
| steve  | 3qlylbzqfr |    3 |
| steve  | o04ksti7di |    3 |
| steve  | 0h22y66kq3 |    3 |
| steve  | hllaazonfl |    3 |
| mike   | 4sxbgyacmj |    3 |
| mike   | pnip9c8cej |    3 |
| mike   | m4q13ln9gc |    3 |
| mike   | hinn6w03wd |    3 |
| mike   | 2dsarwozpm |    3 |
| oliver | gvf9kjewpj |    4 |
| oliver | 24w5s30w5t |    4 |
| martha | bxggn5t6d2 |    8 |
| martha | t05mi47i4n |    8 |
| martha | p30wmw2o6n |    8 |
| martha | wip6efajt9 |    8 |
+--------+------------+------+
```

- Amy, Bob and Oliver are only present in `hi_priority` table and will be selected.
- Mike and Martha are only present in `lo_priority` table and will be selected.
- John and Steve are present in both `hi_priority` table and `lo_priority` table but will be selected only from `hi_priority` table

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a version of MariaDB later than 10.2 (so it supports CTEs), you can use this query. It first gets a list of all the distinct names from `hi_priority` and `lo_priority` (in the `names` CTE), then finds the top 7 names by ordering those by priority and `col2` (the `top7` CTE) and finally joins that list back to `hi_priority` and `lo_priority`, giving preference to values from `hi_priority` over those from `lo_priority`:

```sql
WITH names AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, col2, 1 AS priority
  FROM hi_priority hi
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT name, col2, 2 AS priority
  FROM lo_priority lo
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM hi_priority 
    WHERE name = lo.name
  )
),
top7 AS (
  SELECT name, priority
  FROM names
  ORDER BY priority, col2
  LIMIT 7
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t.name,
       COALESCE(hi.col1, lo.col1) AS col1,
       COALESCE(hi.col2, lo.col2) AS col2
FROM top7 t
LEFT JOIN hi_priority hi ON hi.name = t.name
LEFT JOIN lo_priority lo ON lo.name = t.name
ORDER BY col2, priority, name, COALESCE(hi.id, lo.id)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
name    col1            col2
john    kl7y5tis4yh4    1
john    tiid6iywq02k    1
john    detawgsxz615    1
amy     i6u4hhc1trjk    2
amy     wdpt0t5vtmbt    2
amy     87z5wgdfztwl    2
amy     oj98jjdpb5yv    2
bob     ku8wpf7d6ta9    3
bob     6t7mn60g0g18    3
bob     qv0s7ho3jku6    3
bob     5qgz7dznzwvn    3
bob     mm76nhimm6fu    3
bob     k7nlpksc55t2    3
steve   hllaazonflf0    3
steve   0h22y66kq3ow    3
steve   o04ksti7di60    3
steve   3qlylbzqfr51    3
steve   wmisshywtb12    3
mike    2dsarwozpmci    3
mike    hinn6w03wdib    3
mike    4sxbgyacmjob    3
mike    m4q13ln9gctj    3
mike    pnip9c8cejo9    3
oliver  gvf9kjewpj7h    4
oliver  24w5s30w5te6    4
martha  bxggn5t6d2xn    8
martha  t05mi47i4n6l    8
martha  p30wmw2o6nty    8
martha  wip6efajt9yv    8
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b0855c1d4ff1173bd41aea22cab15081)

If you're running an earlier version, you can write the same query using subqueries:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t.name,
       COALESCE(hi.col1, lo.col1) AS col1,
       COALESCE(hi.col2, lo.col2) AS col2
FROM (
  SELECT name, priority
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT name, col2, 1 AS priority
    FROM hi_priority hi
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT name, col2, 2 AS priority
    FROM lo_priority lo
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM hi_priority 
      WHERE name = lo.name
    )
  ) n
  ORDER BY priority, col2
  LIMIT 7
) t
LEFT JOIN hi_priority hi ON hi.name = t.name
LEFT JOIN lo_priority lo ON lo.name = t.name
ORDER BY col2, priority, name, COALESCE(hi.id, lo.id)
```

Output is the same. [Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8d3dac6b12ace222360837e462bee251)

Comment: the solution works really well on `dfiddle`. Can you kindly suggest a solution that would work for version `10.1.21`?

Comment: @Sandeep please see my edit. The new query should work fine on 10.1